# Caliburn Micro ActivateItem doesn't update binding

Tags: wpf, binding, converters, caliburn.micro

Consider a `ShellViewModel : Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive` where I have 2 ViewModels injected through PropertyInjection. So these viewmodel always have the same instance.

```
public SomeViewModel SomeViewModel {get; set;}    
public AnotherViewModel AnotherViewModel {get; set;}
```

SomeViewModel has a TextBlock that binds the Text to a property (with NotifyPropertyChanged) and has a converter attached.

- The first time I call `ActivateItem(someViewModel)` I will enter the converter defined in `SomeView.xaml`.
- If I then call `ActivateItem(AnotherViewModel)` and again `ActivateItem(SomeViewModel)` I don't enter this converter.

I would expect that calling ActivateItem would always update the bindings and execute the converters again, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm aware that nothing changed to the property itself, and NotifyPropertyChanged is not called. But I would expect that visualizing a usercontrol would refresh the bindings.
As far as I know this is what happens with old-school WPF applications without Caliburn.Micro

Is there a way to make sure that these bindings are refreshed without:

- Calling `Refresh()` in the `OnActivate()` of SomeViewModel
- Publishing an event on the EventAgregator that will be handled in SomeViewModel that will call `Refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of view caching: A `Conductor<T>` is a `Screen`, and a `Screen` is a `ViewAware`. That class is designed to cache view instances: You will notice that the position of a `ScrollViewer` in your first view will stay the same when navigating back and forth between your view models, even if it's not bound to any property.

You can either override the `GetView(object)` method of your view models, like this:

```
public override object GetView(object context = null)
{
    return null;
}
```

This will essentially disable view caching.

Alternatively, you could modify the code for view location to fit your needs. Just add this to your bootstrapper startup:

```
private void CustomizeViewLocation()
{
    var log = LogManager.GetLog(typeof(ViewLocator));

    ViewLocator.LocateForModel = (model, displayLocation, context) => {

        // Either remove the IViewAware handling to completely disable
        // view caching...

        var viewAware = model as IViewAware;
        if (viewAware != null)
        {
            var view = viewAware.GetView(context) as UIElement;
            if (view != null)
            {
                // Or add this custom code to always refresh...

                var propertyChangedBase = model as PropertyChangedBase;
                if (propertyChangedBase != null)
                {
                    propertyChangedBase.Refresh();
                }

                // End custom code.

                var windowCheck = view as Window;
                if (windowCheck == null || (!windowCheck.IsLoaded && !(new WindowInteropHelper(windowCheck).Handle == IntPtr.Zero)))
                {
                    log.Info("Using cached view for {0}.", model);
                    return view;
                }
            }
        }

        return ViewLocator.LocateForModelType(model.GetType(), displayLocation, context);
    };
}
```